# How can I get Compaq Presario V2565US graphics driver?

Tags: graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu and after I installed Ubuntu 12.10 I found that my graphics driver is unknown. Could anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: See also [How do I install extra drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

Comment: If the answers to the duplicates don't resolve the issue, please edit your question to explain why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an app in Ubuntu under `system settings > additional drivers` to find open source drivers online, try that.